# HTML.ActionLink to pass object has Parameter

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

I am trying to pass object type has a  parameter to controller. I tried passing directly the object. Here is the exception:

```
`System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper<dynamic>` has no applicable method 
named `ActionLink` but appears to have an extension method by that name.  
Extension methods cannot be dynamically dispatched. Consider casting  
the dynamic arguments or calling the extension method without the  
extension method syntax.
```

Even though I added code for type casting, but still it throw compile error as above

```
InProgressGrid.Column(header: "File Name", columnName: "FileName",format:(item) => Html.ActionLink(((string)item.FileName), "DownloadReport", (Domain.UserObject)item ,null))
```

Is there any way I can pass more than one parameter to controller action method

```
InProgressGrid.Column(header: "File Name", columnName: "FileName",format:(item) => Html.ActionLink(((string)item.FileName), "DownloadReport", new {FileName = item.FileName,PK= item.PartitionKey },null)),
```

Now when I run application I see only one Attribute ie. FileName is passed but no PartitionKey is passed to Controller 's action Parameter.

Is there any change in Global Routing for above condition to work?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a route:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "ReportDownload",     // Route name
    "Reports/{PK}/{FileName}",                           // URL with parameters
    new { controller = "Reports", action = "DownloadReport", PK = "", FileName="" }  // Parameter defaults
);
```

Just replace the controller name with whatever yours happens to be.